# Addressing data from different sections

Tags: assembly, x86, portable-executable

I'm modifying an executable and wanted to add data into the `.rdata` section. I can read it correctly when working in the debugger, but not when running the standalone patched executable.

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the executable can get loaded in a different base address, which means that the absolute address in my `MOV` instructions aren't actually pointing to my data.

How could I get the loader to correctly translate the address in the appended instructions? or, is it possible to calculate the VA at runtime if I know the RVA?

Comment: So you want to know how to add new relocations / symbol-table stuff to get fixups or whatever is needed for your new instructions that use the address of your new data?  Can you make your code PIC and use RIP-relative addressing?  (Or a 32-bit mode PIC hack)  That will work as long as the distances between the `.rdata` section and the text section stays the same (which it should, I think.)

Comment: Yes. I believe using RIP relative addressing should get the job done, if the distances between sections stay the same. I will look up on that last part and test it. Thanks.

Comment: The `.rdata` and `.text` sections are probably in the same *segment*, i.e. part of the same contiguous mapping by the runtime loader.  That's the case for `.rodata` and other read-only sections in ELF executables/libraries on Linux, and it would seem sensible for Windows to do the same (so libraries could use RIP-relative addressing for private static data without needing relocations).  i.e. it's a useful property to have with no downsides, so there's good reason to hope they implemented it that way.

Comment: if you add some code - it must be base Independent code. or you need add data to relocations section too. or zero relocation section in optional header. at all usually for add data/code  need full rebuild all pe and have perfect knowledge in this topic

Answer (score 0):

You need to also modify the relocation section of the executable

> The .reloc section holds a table of base relocations. A base relocation is an adjustment to an instruction or
>   initialized variable value that's needed if the loader couldn't load the file where the linker assumed it would. If the
>   loader is able to load the image at the linker's preferred base address, the loader completely ignores the relocation
>   information in this section.

As how you should modify this section is beyond me but here you can find the documentation on the .reloc section structure from microsoft: [The .reloc Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#the_.reloc_section__image_only_)